# What is the Greek word for Qavah (Hebrew for "wait") in Isa 40:31

Tags: greek, hebrew, word-study, hermeneutical-approaches, word-choice

> “But they that **WAIT** upon the Lord shall renew their strength; they
> shall mount up with wings as eagles; they shall run, and not be weary;
> and they shall walk, and not faint” (Isa. 40:31).

In this passage the Hebrew word used here for “wait” is Qavah, please what is Qavah in Greek?

Answer (score 2):

In Isa. 40:31, the LXX uses the Greek word ὑπομένοντες to translate the Hebrew קוֹיֵ. ὑπομένοντες is a participle conjugated from the lemma ὑπομένω. Conjugations of ὑπομένω occur 54 times in the LXX and 17 times in the Greek NT.

Answer (score 1):

It is a good question because it seems hard to find, if indeed there is, a direct link between any of those passages in the OT that might be quoted again in the NT.  However, I think you may be looking for the word: προσδέχομαι (Strong's G4327 - prosdechomai).

For example:

> And, behold, there was a man in Jerusalem, whose name was Simeon; and
> the same man was just and devout, **waiting** for the consolation of
> Israel: and the Holy Ghost was upon him. (Luke 2:25, KJV)
>
> καὶ ἰδού, ἦν ἄνθρωπος ἐν ἰερουσαλὴμ ᾧ ὄνομα συμεών καὶ ὁ ἄνθρωπος
> οὗτος δίκαιος καὶ εὐλαβής **προσδεχόμενος** παράκλησιν τοῦ ἰσραήλ καὶ
> πνεῦμα ἅγιον ἦν ἐπ᾽ αὐτόν (Luke 2:25, Greek TR)

It is the same Greek word used here as well.

> (The same had not consented to the counsel and deed of them;) he was
> of Arimathaea, a city of the Jews: who also himself **waited** for the
> kingdom of God. (Luke 23:51, KJV)
>
> οὗτος οὐκ ἦν συγκατατεθειμένος τῇ βουλῇ καὶ τῇ πράξει αὐτῶν ἀπὸ
> ἁριμαθαίας πόλεως τῶν ἰουδαίων ὃς καὶ **προσεδέχετο** καὶ αὐτὸς τὴν
> βασιλείαν τοῦ θεοῦ (Luke 23:51, Greek TR)

And here:

> **Looking for** that blessed hope, and the glorious appearing of the great
> God and our Saviour Jesus Christ; (Titus 2:13, KJV)
>
> **προσδεχόμενοι** τὴν μακαρίαν ἐλπίδα καὶ ἐπιφάνειαν τῆς δόξης τοῦ μεγάλου
> θεοῦ καὶ σωτῆρος ἡμῶν ἰησοῦ χριστοῦ (Titus 2:13, Greek TR)

That last one parallels this text in the OT that uses the Hebrew word in question (Strong's H6960 - qavah).

> And it shall be said in that day, Lo, this is our God; **we have
> waited** for him, and he will save us: this is the LORD; **we have
> waited** for him, we will be glad and rejoice in his salvation.
> (Isaiah 25:9, KJV)
>
> וְאָמַר֙ בַּיֹּ֣ום הַה֔וּא הִנֵּ֨ה אֱלֹהֵ֥ינוּ זֶ֛ה **קִוִּ֥ינוּ**
> לֹ֖ו וְיֹֽושִׁיעֵ֑נוּ זֶ֤ה יְהוָה֙ **קִוִּ֣ינוּ** לֹ֔ו נָגִ֥ילָה
> וְנִשְׂמְחָ֖ה  בִּישׁוּעָתֹֽו׃ (Isaiah 25:9, Hebrew TR)

### Conclusion

While they are different languages, the nearest Greek equivalent seems to be **[προσδέχομαι](https://www.blbclassic.org/lang/lexicon/Lexicon.cfm?Strongs=G4327&t=KJV)** (Strong's G4327 - prosdechomai).

Answer (score 0):

In Isa 40:31, the word translated "wait" is:

- Hebrew: קוֹיֵ֤ (weqow) whose lexical form is קָוָה (qavah) meaning "to wait".  This occurs elsewhere in the Hebrew such as Gen 1:9, 49:18, Job 3:9, 6:19, 7:2, 17:13, 30:26, Ps 25:3, 5, 21, 27:14, 37:9, etc.
- Greek LXX: ὑπομένοντες (hupomenontes) whose lexical form is ὑπομένω (hupomeno) meaning "(a) I remain behind, (b) I stand my ground, show endurance, (c) I endure, bear up against, persevere" (Strongs).

Isa 40:13 is not quoted in the NT anywhere.  However, there may be an allusion to this verse (and possibly also Ps 37:9, 123:2, Isa 30:18, Zeph 3:8 ??) in places like Matt 10:22, 24:13, Mark 13:13, Rom 12:12, 1 Cor 12:12, 13:7, etc, (and possibly) 1 Cor 1:7, 4:5, James 5:7.